# Turning audio and video tags into jw players?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, jwplayer

I have several media elements on various pages, like these two examples:

```
<audio preload="none" controls="controls">
  <source type="audio/mpeg" src="__/no/2015/4/6/2015-4-6-0.mp3" />
  <source type="audio/ogg" src="__/no/2015/4/6/2015-4-6-0.ogg" />
</audio>

<video preload="none" controls="controls">
  <source type="video/mp4"
    src="http://manna.amazingfacts.org/amazingfacts/shows/csh/sssh21545.mp4" />
</video>
```

Only "styled" with `width: 100%` in CSS. Seems to work alright, but looks different in all browsers and there's no fallback to anything.

I might get access to a JW Player key, so wanting to maybe make use of that, but since the HTML is already generated like that, I was wondering if there is an easy way to get the JW Player to just pick those up and setup itself, sort of.

Hope that made sense...?

Been trying to figure something out in the JW Player documentation, but it all seems to be based on starting in javascript, setting up players with sources and so on. Can of course write something manually, pick out the `<source>`s and so on, but hoping there's something automagical built-in... :)